# MySQL search for part of regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a **MySql search** that works fine **with regexp**.
But it only finds full words.

E.g if I search for `apples` in the text "`i really love apples`" **it matches**. But if I search for `apple` I get **no result**.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$search = (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) ? stripslashes($_GET['q']) : $_GET['q']; 
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($search); 
$search = strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s+/', '|', trim($_GET['q'])));

$regexp = "REGEXP '[[:<:]]($search)[[:>:]]'"; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `food` WHERE UPPER(`fruits`) $regexp";
```

I'm really stuck and any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's doing exactly what you ask, if you use the *word-boundary* patterns:

```
$regexp = "REGEXP '[[:<:]]($search)[[:>:]]'";
```

This means that if you search for `apple` it only matches if `e` is the end of the word.  That's what the `[[:>:]]` pattern means.

You can extend the pattern a bit, to include extra alpha characters before the word bounary:

```
$regexp = "REGEXP '[[:<:]]($search)[[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]'";
```

That would allow it to match `apples`, and also `applesauce` for example.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you so much! But i got an error first because of the missing () in the regexp [[:<:]]($search)[[:alpha:]]*[[:>:]]

Comment: Is that for the PHP variable interpolation?  You shouldn't need it for the sake of the regular expression.  I'll edit my answer for future readers.

Comment: is it possible to search "really apple". ?

Comment: @Vincent, why not? You can put whitespace into regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to match a string anywhere in the field content you can just use a [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `food` WHERE UPPER(`fruits`) LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Depending on your table collation the `strtoupper` and `UPPER` statements might be redundant (generally if the collation has `_ci` at the end of it the comparison would be performed in a case insensitive manner).